# Debugging .NET Core Docker Container in VS Code

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, .net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

Inside my project folder I have a .NET Core 2.1 Web API project, an XUnit test project and my docker compose file.

Within my API project I have the following for my Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
ARG NUGET_SOURCE
WORKDIR /src
COPY api/api.csproj api/
RUN dotnet restore api/api.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/api
RUN dotnet build api.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish api.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl unzip
RUN curl -sSL https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh | bash /dev/stdin -v latest -l ~/vsdbg
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "api.dll"]
```

In my docker-compose.yml file I have the following

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  api:
    image: myimage   
    ports: 
      - 5000:80
    environment:
      GoogleKey: thekey
      RedisConnectionString: redis
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: api/Dockerfile
      args:
        NUGET_SOURCE: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
    volumes:
      - app_data:/app
    entrypoint: tail -f /dev/null
    depends_on:
      - redis

  redis:
    image: redis:3.2-alpine
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/data

volumes:  
  redis_data:
  app_data:
```

And in my launch.json file in VS Code I have added the following

```
{
            "name": "Docker",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/app": "${workspaceRoot}"
            },
            "processId" : "${command:pickRemoteProcess}",
            "pipeTransport": {
                "debuggerPath": "/root/vsdbg/vsdbg",
                "pipeProgram": "docker",
                "pipeCwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
                "quoteArgs": false,
                "pipeArgs": [
                    "exec -i myimage_api_1"
                ]
             }
        },
```

From there I run  `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d --build` and then `docker-compose exec api dotnet api.dll`.

I then click the play button in the debug pane for Docker and have tried to attach it to both the tail and api.dll commands but none of my break points are being hit.

What have I missed in my configurations?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the debugger (vsdbg) is working on the alpine images yet but it is reported to being close to working

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/256756/new-container-tools-in-158-cant-debug-alpine-docke.html

https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/2165